# Need property to store completion handler with generic type

Tags: ios, swift, generics, properties

i have defined a typealias like this:

```
public typealias ResponseCompletion<T> = (Result<T>, [AnyHashable: Any]?) -> Void
```

Then i have a class with a related method:

```
public func load<T>(completion: @escaping ResponseCompletion<T>)
```

this works fine until i forward the completion handler from this method to another. But now i have the requirement to store the completion handler for later use.

When i do something like this:

```
class ServiceOperation<T: Any>: Operation {
    private let completion: ResponseCompletion<T>
```

And then try to store the handler

```
    public func load<T>(Result<T>, [AnyHashable: Any]?) -> Void {
        self.completion = completion
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'ResponseCompletion<T>' (aka '(Result<T>, Optional<Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>>) -> ()') to type '(Result<T>, [AnyHashable : Any]?) -> Void'
```

Anyone has an idea, how to define the property correctly so that i can store the completion handler?

Comment: At some point you have to specify a concrete type to be represented by `T`, but not `Any`

Comment: Where did you implement `public typealias ResponseCompletion<T> = (Result<T>, [AnyHashable: Any]?) -> Void {
        self.completion = completion
    }`?!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want to achieve, but this code will store `completion` after you will call `load()` function.

```
struct Result<T> {}
typealias ResponseCompletion<T> = (Result<T>, [AnyHashable: Any]?) -> ()
class ServiceOperation<T: Any>: Operation {
    private var completion: ResponseCompletion<T>?
    public func load(completion: @escaping ResponseCompletion<T>) {
        self.completion = completion
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
ServiceOperation<Int>().load { (result, params) in

}
```

Comment: no, will not. the compiler says `Cannot assign value of type 'ResponseCompletion<T>' (aka '(Result<T>, Optional<Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>>) -> ()') to type '((Result<T>, [AnyHashable : Any]?) -> Void)?'` in the line where you assign `self.completion = completion`